# Update state between tabs/browser sessions when localstorage changes in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have mutations that allow me to update item in VueX state called `complianceList`.

```
   ADD_TO_COMPLIANCE_LIST(state, payload) {
      state.complianceList.push(payload)
    },
```

After this item is added to list I save that updated list using the following mutation:

```
SAVE_LOCAL(state, company_name) {
  localStorage.setItem(company_name, JSON.stringify(state.complianceList))
},
```

Also everytime the component is mounted I get current localstorage data (so on refresh)

```
GET_LOCAL(state,company_name) {
    state.complianceList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(company_name));
}
```

So my question is it possible to update the `complianceList` state variable when localStorage changes? In one tab I added more to the list but in the other tab the change was not updated, only after refreshing the page did the list refresh.

Maybe using some sort of watcher like

```
watch: {
 localStorage.getItem(this.company_name)() (
   this.GET_LOCAL(state,this.company_name)
)
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: How will you change the localStorage? With button click or what?

Comment: Yes with button clicks in different components, using this mutation `SAVE_LOCAL`

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude method, but you can try. Use page reload after doing mutation.

```
watch: {
 localStorage.getItem(this.company_name)() (
   this.GET_LOCAL(state,this.company_name)
   location.reload() // window.location.reload()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `actions` of `Vuex` in this situation.

```
{
  actions: {
    SAVE_LOCAL(context) {
       context.commit('SAVE_LOCAL');
    }
  }
}
```

`dispatch` this `actions` on your button click event.

```
store.dispatch('SAVE_LOCAL');
```

Comment: No it is not the case at all, this does not solve my problem, as you see the issue is that across the tabs I cant see the change because I cant find the way to watch localstorage change. Mutations/actions is not the issue here

Comment: I think it's not a watcher issue. If you want to get and set data from localStorage you don't need watcher. Can you please share more details code?